# Protractor - When opening a popup it doesn't wait for all elements inside this window

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automation, jasmine, protractor

I've tried to make my test to be stable,
but sometimes it's not wait for all elements inside an integrated popup and it's failed.

This test case is little bit complex because it including if statement inside another if statement in order to run the relevant code for FireFox and for Chrome a s well (they have different handling with popup windows),

also the second condition is for case that the user is already logged-in and it should not click on the element of id="loadlogin".

**The CSS of the tested element:**

```
<input type="submit" value="Log in to your PayPal account" id="loadLogin" name="login_button" class="parentSubmit">
```

**Test case - code:**

```
 it('Exisiting Client LiveSite - Payments - Continue To Payment', function () {
    element(by.binding("client_zone.payous.new.continue")).click();
    waitPageToLoad();
});

it('Exisiting Client LiveSite - Payments - Perform a payment by PayPal', function () {
    var loadLogin = element(by.id("loadLogin"));

    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.binding("buttonText"))), 15000);
    element(by.binding("buttonText")).click();

  if (browser === 'firefox') {
        browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {      
            browser.switchTo().window(handles[handles.length - 1]);

            element.all(by.id('loadLogin')).then(function(){

            // expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('www.paypal.com');
              if (loadLogin) {
                    loadLogin.click();
                    browser.driver.sleep(3000);
                                             element(by.id("login_email")).sendKeys("username");
                     element(by.id("login_password")).sendKeys("password");
                    browser.driver.sleep(1000);
                    element(by.id("submitLogin")).click();
                    browser.driver.sleep(5000);
                    element(by.id("submit.x")).click();
                    browser.driver.sleep(10000);
                    console.log("-=-=- first condition - FF -=-=-");
                } else {
                     element(by.id("login_email")).clear();
                     browser.driver.sleep(1000);
                                              element(by.id("login_email")).sendKeys("username");
                     element(by.id("login_password")).sendKeys("password");
                     browser.driver.sleep(1000);
                     element(by.id("submitLogin")).click();
                     browser.driver.sleep(10000);
                     element(by.id("submit.x")).click();
                     browser.driver.sleep(10000);
                     console.log("-=-=- second condition - FF -=-=-")
                }
            });

            browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
                browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
            });
        });
    }

    else {
        browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {      
            browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);

             element.all(by.id('loadLogin')).then(function(){
            // expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('www.paypal.com');
              if (loadLogin) {
                    loadLogin.click();
                    browser.driver.sleep(3000);
                                             element(by.id("login_email")).sendKeys("username");
                     element(by.id("login_password")).sendKeys("password");
                    browser.driver.sleep(1000);
                    element(by.id("submitLogin")).click();
                    browser.driver.sleep(5000);
                    element(by.id("submit.x")).click();
                    browser.driver.sleep(10000);
                    console.log("-=-=- first condition - Chrome -=-=-");
                } else {
                     element(by.id("login_email")).clear();
                     browser.driver.sleep(1000);
                     element(by.id("login_email")).sendKeys("username");
                     element(by.id("login_password")).sendKeys("password");
                     browser.driver.sleep(1000);
                     element(by.id("submitLogin")).click();
                     browser.driver.sleep(10000);
                     element(by.id("submit.x")).click();
                     browser.driver.sleep(10000);
                     console.log("-=-=- second condition - Chrome -=-=-")
                }
            });

            browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
                browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
            });
        });
    };
});
```

**Error:**

```
c:\automation\tests>protractor conf.js
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
imapConnected
LiveSite Portal - Existing client pay by PayPal
  LiveSite - Home Page - pass
  Exisiting Client LiveSite - Payments - Payment form - pass
  LiveSite Portal - Exisiting client payments - Welcome note for existing client
 - pass
  Exisiting Client LiveSite - Payments - Continue To Payment - pass
-=-=- first condition - Chrome -=-=-
  Exisiting Client LiveSite - Payments - Perform a payment by PayPal - fail


Failures:

  1) LiveSite Portal - Existing client pay by PayPal Exisiting Client LiveSite -
 Payments - Perform a payment by PayPal
   Message:
     ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.130)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9
cf),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any sta
cktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 23 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'vCitaQA', ip: '192.168.152.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.ar
ch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEn
abled=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\idan\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir7328
_2982}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, versi
on=43.0.2357.130, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=
true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true,
browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEn
abled=true}]
Session ID: 64d27a4f28d3db93bbb59b8184c87a07
   Stacktrace:
     ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.130)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9
cf),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any sta
cktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 23 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'vCitaQA', ip: '192.168.152.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.ar
ch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEn
abled=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\idan\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir7328
_2982}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, versi
on=43.0.2357.130, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=
true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true,
browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEn
abled=true}]
Session ID: 64d27a4f28d3db93bbb59b8184c87a07
    at new bot.Error (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\
node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113:18)
    at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node
_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\response.js:106:9)

    at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\se
lenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:377:20
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\
promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (C:\Users\idan\
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\
webdriver\promise.js:2464:25)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\np
m\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.
js:563:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.goog.array.forEach (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\array\array.js:203:43)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promi
se.js:552:16)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
Error
    at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:403:21)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as click] (C:\Users\idan\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:76:19)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as click] (C:\Users\idan\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:733:11)
    at c:\automation\tests\payments.js:94:35
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\
promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (C:\Users\idan\
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\
webdriver\promise.js:2464:25)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\np
m\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.
js:563:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.goog.array.forEach (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\array\array.js:203:43)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promi
se.js:552:16)
From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:93:33)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\async-callback.js:45:37)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Block.execute (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:1174:1
7)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31)

    at onComplete (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\nod
e_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2205:18)
    at [object Object].jasmine.WaitsForBlock.execute (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roam
ing\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.j
s:2704:5)
    at [object Object]._onTimeout (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2718:12)
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\payments.js:43:5)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21
)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15)

    at describe (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_
modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\payments.js:1:63)

Finished in 19.473 seconds
5 tests, 3 assertions, 1 failure

[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 failed 1 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1

c:\automation\tests>  element.all(by.id('loadLogin')).then(function(){
'element.all' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

c:\automation\tests>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem could be is that you are not switching to the right window because the order of windows could be dynamic. This is what I would suggest,

> 1. Before clicking on the `loadLogin` button I would save the main window handle. After all window handles are nothing but an array of
>      hash
> 2. When you click on the login, just switch to the window that is NOT main window. This way you can perform login without having to blindly
>      switching to a window. I think this will also simplify your firefox vs
>      chrome logic

So something like this pseudo code,

```
var mainWindow;
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(
    function(handles) {
        mainWindow = handles[0]; //at this point there should be only 1 window
    }
);

browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {      
   handles.forEach(function(handle) {
     if (handle !== mainWindow) {
        browser.switchTo().window(handle);
        element.all(by.id('loadLogin')).then(function(){ 
            //do more stuff
        }
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! your'e solved a mega problem for me! ;)